# Client-side HTTP "GET" Request changes to "OPTIONS" Method?

Tags: node.js, http, axios, xmlhttprequest

I'm building this app with a React UI and a simple Node/Express API.

When I send this request from the client, I get this very weird response. I've never seen this bug before...

[image]

The backend code actually works fine.
I enabled cors in my Node server and when I perform the request from Postman, it just sends me the right response.

This is my server route:

```
router.get("/albums", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.userId;

  const albums = await Album.findAll({ where: { userId: id } });
  res.json(albums);
});
```

This is my server:

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors");
const { sequelize } = require("./models");

dotenv.config({ path: "client/.env" });

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//DB Connection
const main = async () => {
  await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
  console.log("Database synced!");
};
main();

//Routes
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/api"));

const PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 5000;
app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on Port ${PORT}...`
  )
);
```

And this is how I send the request from the client:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getAlbumCollection = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios({
          url: "http://localhost:5000/api/albums",
          method: "get",
          data: {
            userId: isAuth.id,
          },
        });
        console.log(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    };

    getAlbumCollection();
  }, []);
```

It's been a whole day that I'm trying to debug but I don't know what to do.

Thanks!!!

Comment: The OPTIONS method is likely a CORS pre-flight request caused by a non-simple cross origin request.  If the OPTIONS request gets a 2xx status response and appropriate headers, then the browser will then send the GET request afterwards.  You can read about pre-flight requests [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about preflighted requests.

But, maybe because I'm exhausted right now, I still don't get how I can control this stuff with my code.

Comment: If you want to use non-simple cross origin requests, your server HAS to respond to the OPTIONS request appropriately with the right headers and response status.  Or, perhaps you can change your requests to be simple requests and then your server just needs to supply the right headers on the GET response.  Or, you can change the architecture of your system so you don't need cross origin requests.  That MDN article I linked you is the best resource I know of for understanding all this.